# Facebook login using external bearer token (MVC4 Web Api)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api, owin

I'm trying to implement facebook login using external bearer token. I created new project in VS 2013 and selected individual user account authentication like in this tulorial http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/external-authentication-services.

I configured facebook authentication:

```
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
            appId: "123[...]",
            appSecret: "123[...]");
```

And all work fine.

My test method:

```
[OverrideAuthentication]
[HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer)]
[Route("ExternalLogin2", Name = "ExternalLogin2")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetExternalLogin2()
{
    ExternalLoginData externalLogin = ExternalLoginData.FromIdentity(User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity);
    return Ok();
}
```

I don't understand how [HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer)] works.

I invoke GET request in fiddler:

```
GET http://localhost:17353/api/Account/ExternalLogin2 HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer [my facebook token]
Content-Length: 28
Host: localhost:17353
```

But I receive 401 result.

What I must do for authenticating by external bearer token?

Comment: Where are you getting the facebook token from?

Comment: @Neshta Have you found a solution here?

Comment: Same issue here.  I have a facebook token but cannot access a WebAPI method marked with external bearer.

Comment: same problem. I dont understand what the point of this attribute is if it doesn't work. and clearly im not the only one... the solution/workaround would need to do manual API calls for as many providers that are activated... sounds tedious. Here's some code that does that https://github.com/tjoudeh/AngularJSAuthentication/blob/master/AngularJSAuthentication.API/Controllers/AccountController.cs#L295 for Facebook and Google, but I would really like this attribute to work so that this verification code is not neccesary..

Comment: if anybody has solved this, I have a bounty question with this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31093914/verify-access-token-asp-net-identity

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found solution for this problem. But I solved task by another way. I added HTTP header X-Facebook-Token and passed it there. In overrided method GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(context) of OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider I caught the token from context.Request.Headers["X-Facebook-Token"].

```
string facebookToken = context.Request.Headers["X-Facebook-Token"];
if (facebookToken == null)
{
    context.SetError("invalid_grant", "Facebook token was not found in X-Facebook-Token header.");
    return;
}

dynamic facebookUser;
if (!FacebookUtil.TryGetUser(facebookToken, out facebookUser))
{
    context.SetError("invalid_grant", "Facebook token is incorrect.");
    return;
}
```

In FacebookUtil.TryGetUser() I used Facebook library http://www.nuget.org/packages/facebook

```
public static bool TryGetUser(string facebookToken, out dynamic user)
{
    var facebookClient = new FacebookClient(facebookToken)
    {
        AppId = AppSettings.FacebookAppId,
        AppSecret = AppSettings.FacebookAppSecret
    };

    try
    {
        user = facebookClient.Get("me");
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        user = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```