# Verify Access Token - Asp.Net Identity

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I'm using ASP.Net Identity to implement external logins. After user logins in with Google I get google's external access token. I then make a second api call to [ObtainLocalAccessToken()](https://github.com/tjoudeh/AngularJSAuthentication/blob/master/AngularJSAuthentication.API/Controllers/AccountController.cs#L167) which trades the external access token for a new local one.

`ObtainLocalAccessToken()` calls [VerifyExternalAccessToken()](https://github.com/tjoudeh/AngularJSAuthentication/blob/master/AngularJSAuthentication.API/Controllers/AccountController.cs#L175) which verifies the external access token with the provider by manually making http calls and parsing the user_id.

**How can I leverage ASP.NET identity to remove the entire method `VerifyExternalAccessToken()`?**

I believe that's what `[HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer)]` is for isn't it? I want to decorate `ObtainLocalAccessToken()` endpoint with that attribute and send the external_access_token in the header (`{'Authorization' : 'Bearer xxx' }`), and it should populate `User.Identity` without needing to manually verify the external access token? I believe that’s the purpose, however I cannot get it working. I send a valid external access token from google and it gets rejected with a 401.

I have this line in Startup.Auth btw:

```
 app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/AccountApi/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        });
```

Alternatively, it is possible to use "/Token" endpoint to trade an external access token for a local one? Which approach is correct?

Comment: I will make a wild guess here. But every service I use from google are through https. It it possible that you cannot use AllowInsecureHttp = true? Since your error is a 401, I'm pretty sure it means a call to http is not allowed.

Comment: Well I can't use ssl yet so I need it to work using http, like it does from my web application (but not from mobile). But am I correct in my understanding that [HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer)] is supposed to populate the principle when sending an external access token? If so, how would it know which provider the access token is from?

Comment: And besides 401 = Unauthorized. "Authorization has been denied for this request."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Studying the implementation by Taiseer Joudeh

the [`/ExternalLogin`](https://github.com/tjoudeh/AngularJSAuthentication/blob/master/AngularJSAuthentication.API/Controllers/AccountController.cs#L62)  endpoint replaces the **OWIN Authentication Challenge**.

The **AngularJS** `LoginController` makes a call to the [authService.obtainAccessToken](https://github.com/tjoudeh/AngularJSAuthentication/blob/master/AngularJSAuthentication.Web/app/controllers/loginController.js#L56) when an externally authenticated user has not been found in Identity Provider:

```
        if (fragment.haslocalaccount == 'False') {
           ...
        }

        else {
            //Obtain access token and redirect to orders
            var externalData = { provider: fragment.provider,
                      externalAccessToken: fragment.external_access_token };
            authService.obtainAccessToken(externalData).then(function (response) {

                $location.path('/orders');
```

It uses the **[VerifyExternalAccessToken](https://github.com/tjoudeh/AngularJSAuthentication/blob/master/AngularJSAuthentication.API/Controllers/AccountController.cs#L295)** to perform a reverse lookup against **Google** and **Facebook** API's to get claim info for the bearer token.

```
        if (provider == "Facebook")
        {
            var appToken = "xxxxxx";
            verifyTokenEndPoint = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?input_token={0}&access_token={1}", accessToken, appToken);
        }
        else if (provider == "Google")
        {
            verifyTokenEndPoint = string.Format("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token={0}", accessToken);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
```

If token is found, it returns a new **ASP.NET** bearer token

```
        var accessTokenResponse = GenerateLocalAccessTokenResponse(user.UserName);

        return Ok(accessTokenResponse);
```

---

With **`[HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer)]`** the **OWIN Middleware** uses the *external bearer token* to access the 3rd party's Cookie and Register a new account (Or find existing).

**OWIN Middleware** cannot be configured to accept *external bearer token* instead of local authority tokens. *External bearer tokens* are only used for Authentication and Registration.

Comment: Hi Dave,is there some other solution or method built into the OWIN middleware or otherwise that could be called to verify the external provider token? The custom logic of `VerifyExternalAccessToken()` feels hackish/re-inventing the wheel as the method would require updating every time I'd like to add a new external provider. E.g. Twitter. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed, @GFoley83, the `VerifyExternalAccessToken()` is a hack. And OWIN does have baked in methods for consuming OAuth cookies. But none for consuming Authentication *Tokens*. To get the ID behind an OAuth bearer Token, you are at the mercy of the provider.