# OAuth2: Verify Microsoft Account access_token

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token

Does anyone know if there is a way to verify a microsoft account access token?

Like the ones for Facebook and Google are verified here: [Verify Access Token - Asp.Net Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31093914/verify-access-token-asp-net-identity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it myself. See

> Requesting info using REST

on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826533.aspx

Comment: The link is dead :-( Please copy the relevant excerpt to this post next time :-)

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft documentations :

Access tokens

Currently, access tokens issued by the v2.0 endpoint can be consumed only by Microsoft Services. **Your apps shouldn't need to perform any validation or inspection of access tokens for any of the currently supported scenarios.** You can **treat access tokens as completely opaque**. They are just strings that your app can pass to Microsoft in HTTP requests.1
**In the near future,** the v2.0 endpoint will introduce the ability for your app to receive access tokens from other clients. **At that time, the information in this reference topic will be updated with the information that you need for your app to perform access token validation** and other similar tasks.
When you request an access token from the v2.0 endpoint, the v2.0 endpoint also returns metadata about the access token for your app to use. This information includes the expiry time of the access token and the scopes for which it is valid. Your app uses this metadata to perform intelligent caching of access tokens without having to parse open the access token itself.

Source : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-tokens

So, currently there is no such endpoint which can allow us to verify access/refresh tokens.